# Devise gem in rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can any one suggest me how to use Devise gem in rails 2.3.8?

I have problem to find out whether Devise gem is already included into the rails structure or we have to install it?

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, please mark it as correct. Otherwise, update your question to include further information.

Answer (score 0):

I really think this Railscast by Ryan Bates will help you get started, regardless of your version of rails.

[Introducing Devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise)

When I first started using Rails, I was also using 2.3.8, and this railscast, and the one after it, bringing in more advanced concepts, really helped me get a grip on things.